# Is it possible to use Databricks-Connect along with Github to make changes to my Azure Databricks notebooks from an IDE?

Tags: github, version-control, databricks-connect

My aim is to make changes to my Azure Databricks notebooks using an IDE rather than in Databricks. While at the same time implementing some sort of version control.

Reading the Databricks-Connect documentation this doesn't look like it supports this kind of functionality. Was wondering if anyone else has tried to do this and had any success?

Comment: what prevents you from writing the code in the IDE & upload to Databricks?

Comment: @Alex Ott I work for a company who's final product is in Databricks. The team want to take advantage of better development in an IDE and push the changes they have made to the notebooks with proper version control. I was wondering if this was possible using Databricks-Connect, since it allows us to access DBUtils, will it also allow me to make changes to notebooks remotely?

Comment: No, Databricks Connect won't make changes in the notebooks - it's designed to develop the code that will be deployed as jobs, for example, or as libraries that are used by the notebooks.

Comment: If you want to get version control for notebooks, use Databricks Repos. But this work will be done in the databricks UI